# time on LogCat eclipse for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-logcat

is the time on Logcat the finished time or the start time to execute  a task?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's whatever time the log method was called and the message was printed.

Comment: so is it a start or the finish time? You said both right here.

Comment: I don't know what you are getting at, but I really don't think it matters or that it will help in solving whatever your actual problem is.

Comment: it does matter. I want to see which task is doing first. if it shows the start time, I know it was in the order. If it show finish time, then I need to find another way to track the order. Make sense?

Comment: There's no concept of a "task" except in your code. You can print two logs, one when a task starts and another when it finishes. Print something like "start task with id = ..." and "end task with id = ..." (or something else besides an id that is unique to each task). Then you can see when each starts and when each ends and in which order. Bottom line, don't rely on the implementation of something you don't control.